# Bug in Unity 2D gravity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, physics, gravity

I'm writing a script in C# in Unity that essentially functions as a switch to turn gravity on or off for a 2D Rigidbody. When the game starts, gravity should be 0 for the Rigidbody. Then when the user taps the space bar, gravity is supposed to increase to 3 (which is does). Then, however, when the player collides with a gameObject labeled 'InvisGoal', the player should teleport to another location and then gravity should be 0 again. However, the player always falls after coming in contact with InvisGoal and teleporting and I can't figure out why. This is my first project in C# so sorry for any obvious errors.. The script is here:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class BallLaunch : MonoBehaviour {

private Rigidbody2D myRigidBody;
public GameObject Ball;

// Use this for initialization
void Start ()
{
    myRigidBody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ();
    GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().gravityScale = 0f;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update ()
{
    if (Input.GetButtonDown ("Jump"))
    {
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().gravityScale = 3f;
    }
}
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other){

    if (other.tag == "InvisGoal")
    {
        Ball.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().gravityScale = 0f;
        transform.position = new Vector3 (0.61f, 1.18f, 0f);
        return;
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: should it just be `GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>()` instead of `Ball.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>()` when you set to 0?

Comment: Yeah I noticed that after I posted it... unfortunately I think it only simplified the code

Answer (score 2):

```
Ball.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().gravityScale = 0f;
```

**This is likely what is causing the problem.**

It sounds like the RigidBody2D you are referencing to in this line is not the same as the one you retrieved beforehand with GetComponent().

GetComponent returns the component of the GameObject you call it from. Therefore in the code I mentioned above,

```
Ball.gameObject.GetComponent<RigidBody2D>()
```

and

```
GetComponent<RigidBody2D>()
```

would give you an two different RigidBody2D component **if the field Ball does not refer to the same GameObject your BallLaunch script is attached to.**

[[image: Image 1]]

#### Supposing BallLaunch script is attached to the Ball you want to set the gravity of (As picture above)

Simply change:

```
Ball.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().gravityScale = 0f;
```

To

```
GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().gravityScale = 0f;
```

Also, since you already referenced your RigidBody2D in your Start method to the field myRigidBody, you can replace all subsequent GetComponent with myRigidBody.

```
GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().gravityScale = 0f;
```

To

```
myRigidBody.gravityScale = 0f;
```

Comment: In addition, there may be some built up momentum (gravity is an acceleration factor! If they're already moving, they'll continue to move!) Might not be important to the asker, or it might be. Worth mentioning.